# Trying to build a web server and client program in Python

Tags: python, webserver, client-server

I'm trying to finish a project at the school building a web server and client program with GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE functionality. When I'm trying to run the server, client-server gets connected but when I try to open it in browser, it shows empty response and on cmd, it shows below posted error

```
Successfully Connected 127.0.0.1:62690 Traceback (most recent call last): File "Server.py", line 72, in <module> file, fileName, userInput, httpVersion = [str(i) for i in request.decode('utf-8').split('||')] ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

my server.py is here https://gist.github.com/keyur2maru/564abe344f59ee4dd59ae42b7879a394 Can anyone please guide me debugging this error? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol does not have such a thing as a header of the four tokens with `||` as a delimiter as expected by your server code:

```
file, fileName, userInput, httpVersion = [str(i) for i in request.decode('utf-8').split('||')]
```

Please revise your server and client code so that it conforms to the [HTTP protocol](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/rfc2616bis/draft-lafon-rfc2616bis-03.html) standards if you would like a browser to be able to interact with your server. An example of a typical HTTP request should look like:

```
GET /path/file.html HTTP/1.0
```

so the line of your server code in question should be more like:

```
action, file, http_version = request.decode().split()
```

Comment: Can you please explain little more about what should be used as delimiter instead of "||"?